# cannot convert from 'System.Data.Linq.Binary' to 'System.IO.BinaryReader'

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, attachment

my table column is:

```
AttachContent   varbinary   (max)
```

when i try to retrieve the data and i get this below error, i am using linq

**cannot convert from 'System.Data.Linq.Binary' to 'System.IO.BinaryReader'**

Comment: How are you trying to retrieve it? Show us that code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

System.Data.Linq.Binary contains a byte array. You can use it directly like this:

```
Binary binary = //your linq object
byte[] array = binary.ToArray();
```

If you must have a BinaryReader on the byte array you can wrap it up like this:

```
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(binary.ToArray()));
```